# selecting and adding multiple values using IEnumerable in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, ienumerable

Im trying to use IEnumerable so it holds multiple selections so a user can choose more then one value in my listbox.

This is how my ViewModel looks like:

```
    public class CreateViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> SelectedValues { get; set; } 
    public IEnumerable<CoreValue> CoreValues { get; set; }
}
```

This is my GET in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{          
    CreateViewModel model = new CreateViewModel();
    model.CoreValues = AdminRepository.GetAllCoreValues();
    return View(model);
}
```

This how my view looks like:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedValues, new MultiSelectList(Model.CoreValues, "Id", "Name"))
```

How do I code my POST action so that SelectedValues will be used to contain the selected values on the post?

Before Ienumerable I had string declared to CoreValueName in my ViewModel and I did something like this in my POST action which worked perfectly but now I changed it to Ienumerable and I have am not sure how to code so my selectedvalues will be used to contain the selected values in my post.

```
Question question = new Question();
var CoreValueID = int.parse(model.CoreValueName);
var GetAllCoreValuesID = AdminRep.GetByCoreValueID(CoreValueID);             
question.CoreValue.Add(GetAllCoreValuesID);
AdminRepository.AddQuestion(question);
AdminRepository.save();
```

---

This version of my POST action works perfectly beacuse model.SubjectType is declared as string in my  Viewmodel:

```
    [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(AdminCreateViewModel model)
        {

                Question question = new Question();       
                var SubjectTypeID = int.Parse(model.SubjecTypeName);
                var GetAllSubjecTypesID = AdminRep.GetBySubjectTypeID(SubjectTypeID);
                question.SubjectType.Add(GetAllSubjecTypesID);
                AdminRep.AddQuestion(question);
                AdminRep.save();
        }
```

This version of my Post action is not working beacuse `Model.Selectedvalues` is declared as Ienumerable string in my ViewModel. I tried to int.parse my `model.SelectedValues` but that doesnt work with Ienumerable. And `GetByCoreValueID` method takes int as argument so I have no idea how do to this. Do I need foreach?

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Create(AdminCreateViewModel model)
 {
    Question question = new Question(); 
    var CoreValueID = model.SelectedValues;
    var GetAllCoreValuesID = AdminRep.GetByCoreValueID(CoreValueID); //
    question.CoreValue.Add(GetAllCoreValuesID);
    AdminRep.AddQuestion(question);
    AdminRep.save();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have your POST controller action take the view model as argument. Then the `SelectedValues` property will contain a list of values that the user selected:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(CreateViewModel model)
{
    model.SelectedValues will cnotain the selected values from the user here
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah I have my ViewModel as parameter in my POST action. But its the "  model.SelectedValues will cnotain the selected values from the user here " I have problems to code since its Ienumerable :/

Comment: @RammtinAvar, what problems do you have? What are you trying to achieve? I thought you was asking how to fetch the selected values back in the POST action.

Comment: What im trying to achieve is once a user have choosen multiple values from my listbox I want to add those values into my database, before they could just add one value but now it should be possible to add multiple by that I declared an Ienumerable selectedvalues in my viewmodel which get filled in my GET action by all my static corevalues in my database. I don't know how to achieve this in my POST action.

Comment: @RammtinAvar, your question has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC then. It's more about database design and querying a SQL database. I'd recommend you starting a new question in which you explain your database schemas, the database technology you are using to query the database, explain if you are using some ORM, and then ask how to update this database given a list of strings.

Comment: I think you are missunderstanding my issue I will edit my question on the bottom. :)

Comment: I achieved it! I just had to do a foreach loop that converts each item to int and then use my method to get all Ids and then just add them :)